# CountDiv (task from codility.com)

Tags: java, algorithm

I have problem understanding the following question: https://codility.com/programmers/task/count_div/ .

Here is the correct answer with a good result:

```
static int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
    int b = B/K;
    int a = A > 0 ? (A - 1)/K : 0;
    if(A == 0){
        b++;
    }
    return b - a;
    }
```

I found this answer on `Stackoverflow` but I cannot understand it. Why `b = B/K? a = (A-1)/K` in the result we make `b - a`. Is there is special formula for this?

My own solution was using a loop, but it wasn't fast.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the details of the problem here?

Comment: Though, that solution is wrong for `solution(0, 1, 1)`. The answer should be 2, not 3

Comment: @ cricket_007 I fixed the code

Comment: That works :) You could have just changed `A < 0` to `A <= 0` in the original post

Comment: Edit the question to include the gist of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is that you compute the number of integers divisible by K in the range [0, B] and then you do the same for [0, A].
Apply a simple substraction among the two results to find out the number of elements divisible by K in [A, B].

In general, to find the number of integers divisible by K from 0 to X, simply divide X by K. Storing that result in an int will cause it to be automatically truncated down to the nearest integer.

Comment: @user264424 Thank you.

Comment: (Accepting (and up-voting) an answer is quite sincere thanks, short of awarding a bounty.)